# How to scroll div-element acting as a chat window to its bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, scroll

I have prepared a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/40wgdL8w/) for my question:

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to use a (yellow) `div` element for a chat in a multiplayer game.

Unfortunately, the `div` does not scroll to the most recent line that I [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to it.

```js
$('#chatBtn').button().click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var str = $('#chatInput').val();
  $('#chatInput').val('');
  $('#chatDiv').append('<br>' + str);

  var h = $('#chatDiv').attr('scrollHeight');

  //$('#chatDiv').scrollTop(h);

  $('#chatDiv').animate({ // DOES NOT SCROLL TO DIV BOTTOM, WHY?
    scrollTop: h
  }, 1000);
});

$('#chatInput').on('input', function(e) { // ENABLES/DISABLES BUTTON, WORKS OK
  var str = $('#chatInput').val();
  $('#chatBtn').button(str.length > 0 ? 'enable' : 'disable');
});
```

```css
@import url("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css");
div#chatDiv {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="chatDiv"></div>

<p align="center">
  <input id="chatInput" type="text" size="40" />
  <button id="chatBtn" disabled>Send</button>
</p>
```

Please enter 4-5 words into `chatInput` and click the `chatBtn` each time - and you will see the problem: the bottom lines are not shown, the `chatDiv`-element is not scrolled down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following line is not giving height

```
var h = $('#chatDiv').attr('scrollHeight');
```

Replace above line of code with

```
var h =$('#chatDiv').prop('scrollHeight');
```

Rather than using input event you can put one condition on button click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#chatBtn').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();   
         var str = $('#chatInput').val().trim();
          if(str !== ''){
              $('#chatInput').val('');
              $('#chatDiv').append('<br>' + str);
              var h =$('#chatDiv').prop('scrollHeight');
              $('#chatDiv').animate({
                 scrollTop: h
              }, 1000);
           }
        });
   });
```

If you remove input event then don't forget to remove disabled from button.

Comment: Unfortunately `var h =$('#chatDiv').height();` does not fix the problem. Please just enter 4-5 lines in [my jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/40wgdL8w/) and click the "Send" button each time - and you will see that the div does not scroll to the bottom.

Comment: I have updated my answer , you can use var h =$('#chatDiv').prop('scrollHeight');  I hope this will solve your problem.